# C++: getting compilation error related to Inheritance and Interfaces

Tags: c++, inheritance, interface, virtual

I am having trouble with "interface" Operand. I have no clue how to make it work. I am getting compilation error which seems to be on Exp, but I don't know how to fix it.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>

using namespace std;

class Operand{
public:
    Operand();
    virtual int make(list<int> &l) = 0;
    virtual ~Operand();
};

class Sum : public Operand{
private:
    char s;
public:
    Sum(char &s) : s(s){};
    int make(list<int> &l){
        int temp;
        list<int>::iterator it = l.begin();
        for (temp = 0; it != l.end(); ++it)
            temp += *it;
        return temp;
    }
    ~Sum(){};
};


class Exp{
private:
    Operand s;   //This little fella seems to be the culprit
    list<int> l;
    int res;
public:
    Exp(Operand &s, list<int> &l) : s(s), l(l){};
    void run(){
        res = s.make(l);
    }
    int get_res(){
        return res;
    }
    ~Exp(){};
};

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]){
    list<int> l;
    l.push_back(1);
    l.push_back(2);
    l.push_back(3);
    char p = '+';
    Sum s(p);
    Exp e(s, l);
    e.run();
    cout << e.get_res() << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Compiled with this:

> g++ stacko.cpp -std=c++98 -Wall -pedantic -o stacko

This is the error I get:

```
stacko.cpp:31:10: error: cannot declare field ‘Exp::s’ to be of abstract type ‘Operand’
  Operand s;
          ^
stacko.cpp:6:7: note:   because the following virtual functions are pure within ‘Operand’:
 class Operand{
       ^
stacko.cpp:9:14: note:  virtual int Operand::make(std::list<int>&)
  virtual int make(list<int> &l) = 0;
```

If I do this to Exp

```
    Operand *s;
    public:
    Exp(Operand &s, list<int> &l){
        s = s;
        l = l;
    }
    void run(){
        res = s->make(l);
    }
```

I get this other error:

```
/tmp/ccjzYIRI.o: En la función `Sum::Sum(char&)':
stacko.cpp:(.text._ZN3SumC2ERc[_ZN3SumC5ERc]+0x18): referencia a `Operand::Operand()' sin definir
/tmp/ccjzYIRI.o: En la función `Sum::~Sum()':
stacko.cpp:(.text._ZN3SumD2Ev[_ZN3SumD5Ev]+0x1f): referencia a `Operand::~Operand()' sin definir
/tmp/ccjzYIRI.o:(.rodata._ZTI3Sum[_ZTI3Sum]+0x10): referencia a `typeinfo for Operand' sin definir
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Thanks!

## Edit:

The errors were in the destructors:

```
virtual ~Operand(); //wont work
virtual ~Operand(){} //this Will
```

And Exp should be like this:

```
Operand *s;
public:
Exp(Operand &s, list<int> &l) : s(&s), l(l){};
```

Comment: So did you end up solving your problem?

Comment: Yes I did. Now I have 99 problems left, but interfaces ain't one :P

Comment: Awesome, haha! Be sure to select an answer as "the answer" if it helped or solves your problem, or write an answer yourself if you feel there isn't a perfect answer already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In c++ you can not instantiate an abstract class (class that has one or more pure virtual functions). And that is exactly what you are doing at:

```
 Operand s;
```

If you really want to instantiate it, you should substitute all `Operand` pure virtual functions for virtual functions:

Substitute this:

```
virtual int make(list<int> &l) = 0;
```

for:

```
virtual int make(list<int> &l);
```

Comment: I realized that just a few seconds ago :P  Thanks!